# Textblock text selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I have a chat window where each message is a `TextBlock`.  I want to be able to select the text inside my `TextBlocks`.  Google says to use a `TextBox` instead, which I cannot do because they do not support runs, which I am using to create hyperlinks inside my messages.  What options do I have?

Comment: Textbox does support Run statements through XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `RichTextBox` implementation for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

How about making an CustomContentControl with TextBox (with selection style) and a Link in it and play with visibility based on content. Some thing like

```
<myControls:CustomContentControl>
        <Grid>
            // play with visibilty depending on content.
            <CustomLink/>
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource SelectionStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
</myControls:ContentControl>
```

Comment: i like this idea, except links can be anywhere within the message.  i am pretty sure runs are required for this. i'm checking out richtextboxes, but i've never worked with them before.